# Laravel validation rules only ids that belong to a selected related model

Tags: php, laravel, validation, belongs-to, validationrules

Below is a sample of database tables.

posts table:

```
id       name
1        A
2        B
```

comments table:

```
id        post_id       text
1         1             aaaaaaa
2         1             AAAAAAAAAAA
3         2             bbbbbbbbb
4         2             BBBBBBBBBBBB
5         2             b5b5b5b5b
```

Below is my current validation rules.

```
[
     'post_id' => 'required|exists:posts,id',
     'comment_id => 'required|exists:comments,id',
]
```

With the above validation rules, it validates if `post_id` exists in the `id` column of the `posts` table. The same for `comment_id`.

But in my case, if you select post id = `1`, it should validate if `comment_id` is `1` or `2` because only these two comments belong to post id = `1`.

The same if you select post id = `2`, it should validate if the selected `comment_id` belongs to post id = `2`.

Otherwise, the validation should fail even the selected `comment_id` do exist in the `id` column of the `comments` table.

How to make such validation in Laravel 5 or 6?

Comment: Are you using a Validation Request?

Answer (score 2):

Hi here is the way you can do it. I believe you are using the Request class
This snippet will work with or without Request class

```
[
     'post_id' => 'required|exists:posts,id',
     'comment_id' => [
        'required',
         Rule::exists('comments')->where(function($query){
                    $query->where('post_id', request()->post_id)
                          ->where('id', request()->comment_id);
}),
]
```

for more information you can look into docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation

Answer (score 0):

```
'comment_id' => [
        'required',
        Rule::exists('comments')->where(function ($query) use($post_id) {
            $query->where('post_id', $post_id);
        }),
    ],
```